# Which android in-app billing is right?

Tags: android, billing, in-app

I am implementing in-app billing in an android game.  I found that the developer web pages have two completely different guides on different pages.  This one seems to work:
[Preparing Your In-app Billing Application](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html)

This one I have not been able to make work:
[Implementing In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)

I don't know why they show two different ways to do the same thing and I want to make sure I'm using the right one and if there's a difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

The first guide you mention [Preparing Your In-app Billing Application](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html) provides you with helper classes to do all the hard work for you. You are best to follow this guide.

To understand what is happening in the helper class provided you can read the [Implementing In app billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) link.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  They sure don't make that clear in the documentation.  It looks like two different approaches the way they present it without tying them together.

Comment: The key to finding the link is looking at the IabHelper.java file provided by the TrivialDrive sample in the first approach.  It creates the ServiceConnection and binds to the IInAppBillingService, as is described in the second approach.  In most cases the best method is to follow the first approach of integrating In app billing by reusing the helper files provided.